# Google Places API - Place Details : Is the 2 letter Country Code based on any Standard?

Tags: google-places-api

The 'address_components' node, in the Place Details service response of Google Places API, shows a Country Code under 'shot_name'. Does this code follows any particular standard like ISO 3166? In the online documentation (https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details), its seen as if they use the 2-letter postal abbreviation. 
If this is just an abbreviation from Google, is it possible to get the entire list of country codes that Google follows so as to build a mapping? Please advise.
We are currently working on a project that requires to integrate Google Places API with a system that supports both ISO-3166 2 and 3 letter codes.

Answer (score 1):

Countries must be passed as as a two-character, ISO 3166-1 Alpha-2 compatible country code.
As stated here (same for places details): https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete

Comment: This only refers to `componentRestrictions` property for `Autocomplete.options`, but not for the search results in `address_components`.
[Address Types and Address Component Types](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Types) only states that 
"`country` indicates the national political entity, and is typically the highest order type returned by the Geocoder."